# The Design Pattern of Wrapping Exist Event in My Own Class

Tags: c#, .net

all:

This issue comes from my currently working C# project.  In solution, it includes three projects, one is UI project, another is interface project, the third is component project. The basic idea of my solution is UI project can dynamic load the component DLL which inherit interface defined in interface project. And in interface project, I defined two classes, one is a interface which is used by UI project to dynamic load DLL, and this interface defines all exposure entities in component object. And besides this interface, there's another abstract component core class which inherit public interface, and it includes all common operations in actual component object. I draw a plot following to describe my explanation before.

"UI Class ---> Interface <--- Abstract Component Core <--- Actual Component"

And in my design, I use C# BackgroundWorker in abstract component core object. And BackgroundWorker contains two event ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted. In my design idea, these two events should be registered by UI Class. For example, UI class can register its operation when component's BackgroundWorker's progress changing or operation finishing. And another thing is that I don't want to expose BackgroundWorker object in Component Core to UI class, so the BackgroundWorker object is defined in abstract component core, not in interface. So in my raw design, I create two events in interface which accepts same event handler as BackgroundWorker's two events. As following:

```
event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProcessChanged;
event EventHandler<RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> RunWorkerCompleted;
```

And in later some places, I will assign these two event handlers to BackgroundWorker's actual events. Code as following:

```
mBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler ( this.ProcessChanged );
mBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler ( this.RunWorkerCompleted );
```

But I don't like this design. Because the user of componet (here is UI class) assign its event handler to component's event, and it real operation, component will add (+=) this event handler to BackgroundWorker's event handler. So this cause BackgroundWorker will have several same event handler if UI running again and again. The idea situation for me is that: 1-BackgroundWorker's event only can contain one event handler; 2-When user assign event handler to component core's own event, then it can transfer this event handler to BackgroundWorker's event at the same time;

Anyone can give me some workable design idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to solve my problem. I can use add and remove keyword to customer define my event accessor in my component core class. Code as following:

```
        public virtual event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProcessChanged
        {
            add
            {
                lock ( mEventLock ) { mBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += value; }
            }
            remove
            {
                lock ( mEventLock ) { mBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged -= value;}
            }
        }
```

So this can solve my problem. User assigning to component core event can immediately assign the event to BackgroundWorker's related event. This is what I want. So in my above question, two parts of code can integrate into one part of code.